# Chrome and JavaScript slowness with a complex html structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need to find out if Google Chrome has a limit on Javascript execution that may slow down some scripts. I'm sorry in advance i cannot post any HTML or examples, but i will try to explain the problem as thorough as possible.

We have a page with a very complex structure (tables within divs within tables at least 20 levels deep) and there we have the core of the page split into 2 parts: on one side is a list of categories(1000 divs or so), and on the other are attributes that need to be mapped to them(10 or so). The 1000 categories each contain 10 tags within them( 4 span, 1 ul's and 5 divs) can also load their subcategories, increasing the number even more.

now, the main problem is that the attributes need to be dragged to the categories in order to execute the mapping, but then you start to drag, it sometimes takes more than 10 seconds for the dragged element to appear, and up to a minute when you drop it (the actual ajax executed in under half a second).

On Firefox the slowness is not such an issue (the script is still slow, but it executes 10 times faster). Is Chrome limiting the script execution resources? If so, can you give me any ideas on how to circumvent this from happening?

Comment: I have example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821403/chrome-takes-5min-to-render-page-with-js-firefox-only-2-sec
chrome like 5min firefox render page in 1 sec...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have thought Chrome would be limiting resources, it would be good if you tried the app on different operating systems with the stable, beta and dev versions of Chrome, just to see what the results are like across the board.

It's a shame you cannot post example code, a complex HTML structure linked with complex selectors might be the reason behind the slowness, is there no way you can show any HTML + JavaScript, perhaps with no private data in.

If not perhaps just try to simplify the markup and selectors, cannot think of much else, hands are tied without code.

Comment: here is a fiddle with a similar problem. It's ugly, but it proves the point. Just try to drag an item (the gray ones) and you will see a delay in chrome (this is a very simplified version of my structure)

http://jsfiddle.net/PG8M8/9/